# Why does SQL complain that a reference to a join key is ambiguous?

Tags: sql, vertica

Why in the following code does Vertica return an error that `zip3` ambiguous? Since it is used as the key for the left join, it must be equal for both tables.

```
SELECT zip, zip3, city, zip3_name
FROM zip_codes
LEFT JOIN zip3_codes
USING (zip3);
```

This generates the following error:

```
Query 1 ERROR: ERROR:  Column reference "zip3" is ambiguous
DETAIL:  Reference "zip3" could refer to either "public.zip_codes.zip3" or "public.zip3_codes.zip3"
```

I can resolve this by selecting either `zip.zip3` or `zip3.zip3` or `COALESCE(zip.zip3, zip3.zip3)` but I'm curious why this would be necessary.

Comment: @steveo314 of course it is in both tables - otherwise, `USING` wouldn't work.

Comment: Could you try using `*` for the list of the columns in the projection?

Comment: Postgres does not generate this error so you should remove the tag:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=e649eec27333ef3dfcd73d20e68c050f.

Comment: PostgreSQL and Vertica are different things.  How does your question involve PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While at first sight it may seem that the columns must always be the same, it's not really the case. The `JOIN` is actually a `LEFT JOIN`, which returns all the rows in the first table and all possible matches from the second, giving `NULL`s when there is no match.

Unmatched records from `zip_codes` will result in different values in `zip.zip3` and `zip3.zip3`, exactly the first giving a value and the second being `NULL`, so it's not really equivalent to exchange those in this particular case, you'll need to determine which columns from which table you need and disambiguate with its table name.

Besides, even if that's weren't the case, the error would still popup. If we change your `LEFT JOIN` to an `INNER JOIN`, your assumption would be true and the columns will always have the same value, yet you would still get the very same error.

The reason for this is that the SQL analyzer is not clever enough to realize the values are always the same. By the standard, if your query references columns with the same name from different tables you **must** specify from which table it is. No further attempt to resolve the ambiguity is done.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how does Vertica resolve the ambiguity with `SELECT *` (which runs correctly per @Sergey Kalinichenko) but not with `SELECT zip, zip3, ...`?

Comment: @prototype `SELECT *` selects every single column from every single table, so there is no ambiguity. You'll see both `zip3`, one from each table. The ambiguity comes from the code not being able to tell which one are you talking about., but with `*` it's simple: both.